# DB2 - If table is empty for date X, insert, else go on

Tags: db2

--DB2 version 10 on AIX

I have a stored procedure, which I need to update.  And want to check if there is data for a certain date.  If data exists, go on, else run insert and then go on.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1_STEP1 
    WHERE XDATE = '9/27/2014' < 1)
  THEN (INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE1_STEP1 (SELECT * FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE2 FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY))
END IF;
```

This errors-out.

> DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N An unexpected token "(" was found following "/2014') < 1) THEN". Expected tokens may include: "". SQLSTATE=42601

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably want the `less than` sign **outside** of the parenthesis...

---

However, as an aside, you can also do this kind of statement without an `IF` (although, I don't have an AIX DB2 available to check for sure. It worked on DB2 for z/OS and LUW, however):

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA1.TABLE1_STEP1
    SELECT *
    FROM SCHEMA2.TABLE2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM SCHEMA1.TABLE1_STEP1 
        WHERE XDATE = '9/27/2014'
    )
    FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Also, you're not providing an `ORDER BY` on the `SCHEMA2.TABLE2` select, so your results could come back in any order (whatever is "easiest" for the database engine)... order is not guaranteed unless you provide the `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.  This is the way I'd do it, too (or something similar).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yep, I misread the question. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and correction.  For some reason, I couldn't reply at work.  I tried moving the parenthesis, but it didn't work. 

Just for knowledge-sake, is there a way to do it with `If` ?

Comment: @AlHowarth - I'm pretty certain that `IF` requires the use of a stored proc, and that you can't run it as one statement.  If you were, perhaps you needed two sets of parenthesis (one for the `IF` condition, one to wrap the statement before the `<`), or use `HAVING(*)` (although I still recommend doing it this way).  Side note - it's preferable to use ISO formatting with dates (`YYYY-MM-DD`), as you're less likely to be effected by server/user formats.